# RE pandas resample

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

Been trying to take an average of a month worth of data but I wanted to check that:

```
df=df.resample('M').mean()
```

Does give the monthly mean and NOT the mean of the last calander day of month

Also I've seen `W-Mon` which would give an average of the monday at a frequency of a week. What would be the equivalent to compare the monthly average of October over multiple years.
I thought it would be this- but it doesn't seem to recognise the command

```
df=df.resample("M-OCT").mean()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
df.assign(y=df.index.year, m=df.index.month).query('m==10').groupby(['y', 'm']).mean()
```

PS if you need a neat and tested answer please post sample data set and desired output in your question...

Comment: Data is to big to upload on here :/ I tried your suggestion:

AssertionError: Grouper and axis must be same length

Comment: @SLE, you should post a __sample__ data which would help to solve your question (5-10 rows would be enough). Anyway, i've updated my answer - please check

Comment: that is perfect. Thank you very muich. And I definetly will next time